# Determine if the plane is parallel to $x-2y+z=2.$

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, plane-geometry

Determine if the plane

$$\pi_1=\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    x & = & 1+4s+7t \\
    y & = & 2+5s+8t \\
    z & = & 3+6s+9t
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Is parallel to the plane $\pi_2=\{x-2y+z=2\}$.

**My attempt:** For the planes to be parallel, they can not intersect anywhere. This implies that the planes can not have any common point in space. Setting in the values of $x,y,z$ given in terms of $s$ and $t$ in $\pi_1$, we have that

$$\pi_2=(1+4s+7t)-2(2+5s+8t)+3+6s+9t=2.$$

If the above equation holds for any $s$ and $t$, then the planes are not parallel. If it doesn't hold for any $s$ and $t$, then the planes are parallel. So simplifying gives

$$\underbrace{4s-10s+6s}_{=0}+\underbrace{7t-16t+9t}_{=0}=2\Leftrightarrow0=2.$$

This means that $\nexists s, t$ that solves the equation, thus the planes are parallel.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: Where does that $5$ in the last equation come from?

Comment: I would say that if $(x,y,z)$ is on the plane $\pi_1$ then $x-2y+z=\cdots=0$ and so $(x,y,z)$ is not on $\pi_2$.

Comment: Do you now see where the five comes from? ok but other than that, is the resoning correct?

Comment: The question is unedited; the $5$ remains a mystery.

Comment: Sorry, supposed to be a 2 ofc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple way would be to determine the normal vector of each plane and if they are multiples of each another, you have two parallel planes. This is easy to do for the second plane, and you should be able to do it for the first plane too with some rearrangements.

Comment: Thanks for your input! However, is my approach correct too? Seems like noone answered that.

Comment: Yes! The Only way for planes to not intersect is when they are parallel. You have attempted to find the intersection points of two planes and used a reverse argument. This makes sense and is valid

Comment: Thanks! This question appeard on an exam today and gave 5 points. Good to know I got'em all :)

Answer (score 2):

For planes to be parallel each vector from one plane should exist on another

So if $(4,5,6)\in \pi_1$ then must be $(4,5,6)\in \pi_2$ and similar for $(7,8,9)$. You can prove it if you add on any point from $\pi_2$ 4 to x, 5 to y, and 6 to z the equation stays true. Also for 7,8,9